# can't find "this" in jquery overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay

Using the overlay tools in jquery-1.2.7.tools.min.js.  I have several div's set up as overlays on an 'img' and some 'a' tags.

```
<img src="/image/test.png" rel="#1485">
<div id="1485" class="simple_overlay">
    <a rel="1486">1</a>
    <a rel="1487">2</a>
    <a rel="1488">3</a>
<div id="1486" class="simple_overlay">
    <a rel="1486">1</a>
    <a rel="1487">2</a>
    <a rel="1488">3</a>
<div id="1487" class="simple_overlay">
    <a rel="1486">1</a>
    <a rel="1487">2</a>
    <a rel="1488">3</a>
```

When I click on one of the 'a' links, I want the overlay div matching its id to be shown, and the others to be hidden.  But, in using jquery code like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('img[rel]').overlay({
            oneInstance: false
        });

        $('a[rel]').overlay({
            oneInstance: false,
            onLoad: function (event) {
                $('.simple_overlay').not($(this)).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

or in using this:

```
$(this).siblings().hide()
```

the "this" designation does not do what I want.  Essentially, all divs with class .simple_overlay are hidden on the hide() call.  I want the div with the clicked rel id to be shown, and the others hidden, but it seems I'm mistaking what "this" is...Can anyone tell me what "this" is in this context?

Comment: `this` refers to the function you are in at that moment. So that will probably not work. My guess is that you need to use the parameters that you can pass into the function call

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a DOM element when you are inside of a callback function (in the context of jQuery), for example, being called by the click, each, bind, etc. methods.

So .overlay() would need to specify a call back function in order to know what "this" we are talking about.

Try this to debug:

```
console.log($(this));
$('.simple_overlay').not($(this)).hide();
```

if the console shows that  $(this) is undefined you may want to think about modifying your code to use an event bind rather than an anonymous function

You could always bind the selector you want to a click event and hide it that way though

```
$('.simple_overlay').on('click', function() {
           $(this).hide();
        }
    });
```